# Why does unboxing occur in this case?

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, jls, unboxing

According to the [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html), the

> Converting an object of a wrapper type (Integer) to its corresponding primitive (int) value is called unboxing. The Java compiler applies unboxing when an object of a wrapper class is:
>
> - **Passed as a parameter to a method that expects a value of the corresponding primitive type.**
> - **Assigned to a variable of the corresponding primitive type.**

Why does unboxing occur in this case?

```
char l = 0;
int arr[] = new int[]{1,2,3};
System.out.println(arr[new Integer(1)]);
```

Where in this scenario does either of those things happen? Is there an underlying method that governs element access in an array? Or does [] imply some sort of variable?

Comment: I think I might have the answer to my question. So is get() invoked whenever we used [<some int >] ? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#get-java.lang.Object-int-

Comment: Yes, array indices are `int` in Java.

Comment: You are linking to a tutorial and quoting from it, not JLS. While what’s in the tutorial is true, it does not tell the whole truth.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you index an array with a long int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27333879/can-you-index-an-array-with-a-long-int)

Comment: @Ole V.V thanks for the suggestion, I have made an edit

Comment: @Hulk not really, my question is specifically about the operation of unboxing..

Comment: Well, unboxing occurs if you provide an `Integer` where an `int` is required. The linked question clarifies that an `int` is indeed what is required here, and you provide `new Integer(1)`, which is a boxed `Integer`.

Comment: @Hulk, thank you for helping, if you have any source to back that claim I would appreciate it.

Comment: The answer can be found in [JLS, §15.10.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.3): "*The index expression undergoes unary numeric promotion ([§5.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6)). The promoted type must be int, or a compile-time error occurs.*"

Comment: [JLS 10.4 Array Access](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.4): "Arrays must be indexed by `int` values;"

Comment: @Turing85, thanks for that link, seems to answer my question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [JLS 15, §15.10.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.3) is pretty clear on this one:

> ...
>
> The index expression undergoes unary numeric promotion ([§5.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6)). The promoted type must be `int`, or a compile-time error occurs.
>
> ...

Similar paragraphs can be found in older JLSes, e.g. [JLS 8, §15.10.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.3).

Answer (score 1):

The unboxing occurs on line three

```
System.out.println(arr[new Integer(1)]);
```

`arr` is an array as declared on line two

```
int arr[] = int[]{1, 2, 3};
```

Note that the type of `arr` is an "array of int".  All arrays accept an `int` for the index being accessed.  In line 3, you are passing an `Integer`, these two types are not the same.  One is a primitive type, while the other is an `Object` type.  Since there exists a "unboxing conversion" to change the `Integer` to an `int`, unboxing occurs just before the value is passed as an index into the `int` array.

Comment: Hi Edwin, would you say the Java Tutorial I linked to is wrong as I don't see anywhere the Integer Object was passed as a parameter to method requiring a primitive int or assigned to a primitive variable.

Comment: @JeffreyK.A What the tutorial does say is fully correct. It doesn’t tell you everything. It’s not the point of tutorial to give the full story. You are correct that the tutorial is not telling us that we may use an `Integer` object for an index. Even though this is possible. And involves auto-unboxing.

Answer (score 0):

In `(arr[new Integer(1)]` the wrapper Integer gets converted to primitive type, because it is used as an array index.