# Create Iterator up to LONG.MAX_VALUE number of elements

Tags: java, arrays, scala, iterator

I can create an iterator of INTEGER.MAX_VALUE elements via:

```
class MyClass {
// irrelevant details
}

private def expandMyClass(notExpanded: Iterator[MyClass], amount: Int): Iterator[MyClass] = {
  notExpanded.flatMap(c => {
    Array.fill(amount)(MyClass())
  }
}
```

How can I create iterators up to LONG.MAX_VALUE? Java collections seem to have a max number of elements up to INTEGER.MAX_VALUE. Something like this:

```
private def expandMyClass(notExpanded: Iterator[MyClass], amount: Long): Iterator[MyClass] = {
  notExpanded.flatMap(c => {
    Array.fill(amount)(MyClass()) // amount is a Long, won't work here
  }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure `Array.fill()` actually creates an array... that's a bad idea for `MAX_INT`, it's a *really* bad idea for `MAX_LONG`. No computer has that much memory, or ever will. You want to create a lazy iterator - you don't need to store everything to be able to meet the interface of `Iterator`.

Comment: You could use `Iterator.continually` and then take only the number of items you want maybe. Depends your use case: what do you want to do with it after?

Comment: Scala arrays reuse Java functionality. And Java arrays can't be long-indexed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27333879/can-you-index-an-array-with-a-long-int